# Run groovy script from bash script

Tags: bash, jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration, cd

I want to run a Groovy script from within bash script.

I have a groovy script that is creating a variable I need from jenkins. (The whole CI is written in bash for some reason).

I need to run it in groovy because I can't reproduce it in bash.

So my bash code looks like:

```
LAST_SUCCESSFUL_BUILD_DATE=$(groovy scripts/jenkins-lastbuild-date.groovy)
```

The groovy script is in the folder scripts, and it's like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

def envVars = Jenkins.instance.getGlobalNodeProperties()[0].getEnvVars()

// the job name is a global Jenkins variable, so I get it from there
def item = Jenkins.instance.getItem(envVars['JOB_NAME'])

def  ff=item.getLastSuccessfulBuild()
println ff.getTime().format("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

but when I run it I get the error

```
line 254: groovy: command not found
```

any ideas? I need to get the date from the last successful commit.

Comment: If I understand you right, this doesn't make sense. You can't just access Jenkins APIs from that script. What about running that code in your pipeline and providing the required information to the bash script as environment variable?
`env.LAST_SUCCESSFUL_BUILD_DATE = ff.getTime().format("yyyy-MM-dd")`

Comment: Well, ideally I would do that.. however the pipeline is all written in bash, so would I be able to trigger the script from it? so like the CI is written in shell scripts too like
```ci/pdf/script.sh
ENVIRONMENT="$(cat ".pdf-bundle-url")"
export ENVIRONMENT`

Comment: Then better migrate to Jenkins Pipelines.. or split it up and extract pieces bit by bit.

Comment: Ideally I would migrate it, but its a long pipeling... hmmm can i have just a groovy script for the pipeline for that?

Comment: you can't call these Jenkins Java API from the outside. You would have to query the Rest / XML API (append `/api/` behind the job URL).

Comment: as for your specific issue, the bash script can not find groovy. You would need to specify groovy with a fully qualified path, e.g. `$(/some/path/groovy ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a problem with environmental variables, as you're trying to localise `groovy` using env in the shebang.

I'd make two things:

1. Get details where groovy is installed

Go to the server and try to run:

```
mbp:~ jhartman$ which groovy
/usr/local/bin/groovy
```

2. Then replace the 1st line of your script with the exact location:

> ```
> #!/usr/local/bin/groovy
> import jenkins.model.Jenkins
> ```

Best regards,
Jarek